# sending text to new activity

Tags: java, android

i have a relative view with different images each time i click on an image i want a unique text to be sent to another activity. i have been able to achieve this for the first image but i cant get the second image to send the text to next activity.
my code for the first-activity:

```
        b1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.native_amala);
        b2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.native_fufu);
        b3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.native_jollof);
        b4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.native_ofada);
        b5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.native_porridge);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                TextView foodName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amala_text_view);
                Intent intent = new Intent(NativeFoods.this,AddToCart.class);
                intent.putExtra("Amala",foodName1.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                TextView foodName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fufu_text_view);
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(NativeFoods.this,AddToCart.class);
                intent2.putExtra("fufu",foodName1.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent2);
            }

        });

    }
```

My second activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_to_cart);

        foodView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cart_item_text_view);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("Amala");
        foodView.setText(str);
```

Comment: You are getting the same key in `getStringExtra`

Comment: try to use the same keys for `intent.putExtra`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to understand how `putExtra` works.

You can put some value with keys, for e.g.

```
intent.putExtra("Amala",foodName1.getText().toString());
```

Here, `Amala` is the key and `foodName1.getText().toString()` is the value.

Then in your next activity you can retrieve the value from key.

i.e. you can do,

```
String str = intent.getStringExtra("Amala");
```

In your click listener of `b2` `ImageView`, you are mentioning the key `fufu` but in your second activity you are getting `Amala`.

You need to keep common key for all click listeners and then retrieve data from that key in second activity.

Comment: this was very helpful, all i needed was to understand how putExtra works

Answer (score 2):

`intent.putExtra(String key, String value)` is the format.

Have a unique key for all `putExtra` functions and use that key in `getStringExtra`

Answer (score 1):

You should use Same **KEY** .

> Intent putExtra (String name, 
>                   Parcelable[] value)

```
intent2.putExtra("value",foodName1.getText().toString());
```

And

```
 Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
 String str=bundle.getString("value");
 foodView.setText(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep common key for all click listeners like this way to send data

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

            TextView foodName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amala_text_view);
            Intent intent = new Intent(NativeFoods.this,AddToCart.class);
            intent.putExtra("data",foodName1.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

            TextView foodName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fufu_text_view);
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(NativeFoods.this,AddToCart.class);
            intent2.putExtra("data",foodName1.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent2);
        }

    });
```

now receiv e data in other activty like this

```
 foodView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cart_item_text_view);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String str = intent.getStringExtra("data");
    foodView.setText(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sending Some Text form one Activity to another activity
You can Simply use putExtra() function

```
putExtra(Sting Key, String value);
```

Let say you have String variable

```
String str = "Hello";
```

After when go to next Next Activity

```
Intent Intent = new Intent(getApllicationContext(),Your_Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("Hello");
startActivity(intent);
```

When you want this variable in Your_Activity then simply in onCreate() method

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String str = intent.getStringExtra("Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

You using the key is fufu.

```
intent2.putExtra("fufu",foodName1.getText().toString());
```

So u get the value then used that key.so change getStringExtra key name change  "amala" to "fufu"

```
foodView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cart_item_text_view);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("fufu");
        foodView.setText(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("VALUES", someValues);
startActivity(intent);
```

Access that intent on next activity

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("VALUES");
```